# Where can I find the database file in android virtual machine

Tags: android, sqlite, adt, sqliteopenhelper

I am developing an app on Android. 
When I'm debugging, I use a virtual machine with android 4.0. 
I have looked in all folders from the system (virtual machine), but can not find where the database (. Db) is stored. 
When I debug the code, I noticed that the eclipse passes in the class constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper (`super (context, DATA_BASE, null, VERSION_DB);`), ie, the database exists.

Answer (score 0):

please go on this steps

1. run your app on emulator
2. click the "window" button on the title bar
3. select the open perspective on it's list view
4. select the DDMS option[this will return to a new page]
5. On that new window select your emulator (on the left side of your window it will show your currently working emulator's from that select the one that you run the app)
6. Then it will display all the files on your system
7. From that go to "data" file
8. Again in that data file there is another file call on "data" click it
9. then it display your application name's by it's package name
10. select the package that you run early
11. On that file there is a folder call "Databases" if and only if your database was created when you running the application.
12. on that there is a file in your data base name. that is your db file
13. if you run on emulator you can view it, but if you run on phone you haven't permission for view it.
14. follow this link if you want to view your db
    [How to view my SQ-LITE DB on ANDROID](http://handtostandincordingfromisuruudith.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-view-sqlite-data-of-android.html)